# How to update activeX Script task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, activex, ssis-2008, ssis-2016

We are migrating some packages from sql server 2008 to 2016. But the ActiveX script task isn't loading correctly. 
I am very new with this tools. I would like to know how to update this kind of task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The ActiveX Script Task has been dropped in SSIS 2012.

You have to rewrite a similar logic using some SSIS Tasks *(file system, for loop ...)* or you can create a DLL that contains the script and use it within the Script Task.

In addition, based on [Discontinued Database Engine Functionality in SQL Server 2016 article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/discontinued-database-engine-functionality-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017)

> ActiveX subsytem is discontinued. Use command line or PowerShell scripts instead.

**References**

- [When migrating ssis packages from 2005 to 2012 Activex Script Task component doesn't exist in 2012 version](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/05edf6e5-dff7-4ba4-b8cb-bb327c5de61b/when-migrating-ssis-packages-from-2005-to-2012-activex-script-task-component-doesnt-exist-in-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [FAQ - How to convert ActiveX Script to native SSIS](https://help.sentryone.com/dtsxchange/scr/ActiveX%20Script%20Task.htm)